# Difference between pgfkeys that use .estore and .store for subscripts

Tags: pgfkeys

The following MWE yields two different subscripts for pgfkeys that use `.estore` and `.store` and seems like the one with the `.store` produce the correct subscript.

What is the reason of this difference? Is it a conflict with `amsmath`?

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/sdof/.is family, /sdof,
    disp text estore/.estore in = \disptextestore,
    disp text store/.store in = \disptextstore,}

\newcommand{\sdof}[1][]{\pgfkeys{/sdof, #1}
    \node at (0,0) {\disptextestore};
    \node at (2,0) {\disptextstore};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \sdof[disp text estore=Estore: $x_{\text{s}}$,
          disp text store=Store: $x_{\text{s}}$,]
    \node at (4, 0) {Typical: $x_{\text{s}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing with is not related to `pgfkeys`, but comes from the combination of `\edef` and `\protect`.

Let me consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\def\foo{
  \displaystyle \text{D},
  \textstyle \text{T},
  \scriptstyle \text{S},
  \scriptscriptstyle \text{SS},
}
\edef\bar{\foo}
\begin{document}
$\foo \quad \bar$
\end{document}
```

The result is like this and you will find that `\text`s do not respect the preceding `\...style`s in `\bar`.

[image: non-working \text]

This is because of the fact that the `\text` command is defined in `amstext.sty` as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\text}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text@\else\expandafter\mbox\fi}
```

This means `\text` is a self-`\protect`ed command and thus safe in most contexts, but `\protect` won't survive inside an `\edef` because `\edef` is a TeX primitive.

Robust commands inside an `\edef` sometime work. For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\makeatletter
\def\foo{
  \displaystyle \text{D},
  \textstyle \text{T},
  \scriptstyle \text{S},
  \scriptscriptstyle \text{SS},
}
\let\@@protect\protect
\let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
\edef\bar{\foo}
\let\protect\@@protect
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\foo \quad \bar$
\end{document}
```

will give the expected result (and this is what `\protected@edef` and `\protectded@xdef` do). However, this depends on the situation.

[image: protected]

You can also benefit from the e-TeX's `\protected` (possibly using the `etoolbox` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\robustify{\text}  % this utilizes the e-TeX's low-level feature instead of LaTeX's high-level protection.
\def\foo{
  \displaystyle \text{D},
  \textstyle \text{T},
  \scriptstyle \text{S},
  \scriptscriptstyle \text{SS},
}
\edef\bar{\foo}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\foo \quad \bar$
\end{document}
```

That being said, my recommendation is to avoid using the `.estore in` handler unless absolutely needed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Whenever I have an isssue that I cannot identify the reason of, it ends up at the back alleys of TeX!