# Definition of \protect in \edef

Tags: expansion, latex-base

**Update**: With the release of LaTeX2e 2018-04-01 Patch level 2, the following sentence has been added in the paragraph cited below to make the documentation clearer:

> More precisely, whenever the content of an `\edef` or `\xdef` etc. can contain arbitrary user input not under the direct control of the programmer, one should use `\protected@edef` instead of `\edef`, etc., so that `\protect` has a suitable definition and the user input will not break if it contains fragile commands.

---

In an attempt to post [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404023/94691), I noticed `source2e.pdf` says in Section 11.4

> The method LaTeX uses for making fragile commands robust is to precede them with `\protect`. This can have one of five possible values:
>
> - [...]
> - `\@unexpandable@protect`, for writing a moving argument to a file. So `\protect\foo` will write `\protect\foo` followed by a space. This value is also used inside `\edef`s, `\mark`s and other commands which evaluate their arguments fully.

However, I don't understand what "This value is also used inside `\edef`s" means here. `\protect` is `\let` to be `\@unexpandable@protect` inside a `\protected@edef` as noted in the aforementioned answer, but I don't think one can alter the definition of `\protect` inside an `\edef`.

What's the point of this statement? Do I have some misunderstanding?

Comment: I interpret it to mean that if `\def\a{xyz}`, then after `\edef\tmp{\protect\a}`, the macro `\tmp` will contain the tokens `\protect xyz`, so that `\protect` remains as `\protect`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ah got it. I misread "This value" as `\protect`, but it should obviously refer to `\@unexpandable@protect`. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: Should I close/delete this question as the confusion is purely due to my poor English comprehension and my question is off-topic here?

Comment: You could delete it if you wanted to, or you might wait a bit to see if one of the TeX heavy hitters chimes in with some interesting tidbits of how it all works.

Comment: The quoted text is a bit confusing. `\protected@edef` will do `\let\protect\@unexpandable@protect` then it will do the `\edef`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes typically it won't do that (if `\protect` is set up fro `\edef` then `\tmp` will contain `protect\a` after the `\edef`

Comment: @yudai-nkt it isn't your bad understanding, it's our bad english:-)  I think actually most of that wording is older than `\protected@edef` so what it means was "you should set `\protect` to this value (`\@unexpandable@protect`) before using `\edef` or `\mark`, although it could now be worded as saying, use `\protected@edef` not `\edef` as it sets up `\protect` to mean `\@onexpandable@protect`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't know that `\protected@edef` is a rather new macro and that people needed to manually switch the meaning of `\protect` to be `\@unexpandable@protect` (I've been using LaTeX only for 5 years). Thank you for your historical supplement.

Comment: @yudai-nkt "new" as in when we made latex2e in 1993-1994 :-)  the `\protect` mechanism itself goes back to latex2.09 but the more systematic use of it, and that documentation comes from that time

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\protected/`\unexpanded` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is a bit misleading and I think we can/should improve on that.

Better would be something stating that LaTeX internally doesn't use `\edef` unless the input is known to be always "safe" but instead uses `\protected@edef` which sets `\protect` to  `\unexpandable@protect` so that any command "protecting" itself is not expanded but survives the `\edef` expansion unaltered.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. By the way, is this kind of "documentation" problems allowed to be filed at GitHub issues? I once considered doing so and consulted the contribution guide, but I wasn't sure if GitHub was appropriate for such non-technical discussions.

Comment: @yudai-nkt well ... a) officially the github version is not yet live (we are just setting it up (perhaps there should be a big disclaimer but ...) but it will be soon. b) if phrased as a question like you did here the answer is "no" (for LaTeX2e at least). Questions are much better asked here with many people helping to get you answer. If it is clearly a bug (and especially you know the answer or direction) then the a documentation bug report is fine as an issue. But as you can see from the draft contribution guide and the template draft we really wish to limit the tracker for LaTeX2e.

Comment: Once we are ready with the github site I guess we will put out a question (and answer) here that discusses how and what to report there for LaTeX2e.

Comment: OK, I see. When I encounter a similar problem in the future, I'll ask here first and migrate the question to GitHub if it turns out to be worth the issue tracker (after the repository is set up of course).

Comment: yes please. It is just a question of resources: a handful of maintainers viz a whole site of people with knowledge ready to help (in case it is not a bug - or even if). and it helps keeping the Issue tracker relevant to actual bugs.