# \text{ } subscript size in tikzmath macro is not correct

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

This question is related to [this earlier TeX-SE question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403998/difference-between-pgfkeys-that-use-estore-and-store-for-subscripts)

I would like to have a proper text subscript using the \text{}  command. It does not seem to work with the tikzmath macros. Please see the following MWW:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

%%%To fix the text subscript
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\makeatletter
%\robustify{\text}
%\makeatother 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node at (0,0) {$\text{b}_\text{b}$: Correct};

    \tikzmath{let \test=\text{b}_{\text{b}};}
    \node at (0,-1cm) {$\test$: Not Correct};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen from the output, the subscript size is not correct:
[image: Subscript size is not correct]

If I apply the suggest fix, the subscript size is corrected:
[image]

My question is the use of `etoolbox` and `robustify` the suggested way of fixing the `\text` subscripts, which may have some side effects that I may face in the future, or is there a more robust way of correcting the size?

**Note:** Use of `\textrm` does not work in the above example, which I used for the problem I have reported in my earlier post.

Comment: There should be an additional set of braces around `\text{b}` for semantic reasons: `b_{\text{b}}`

Comment: @Skillmon: Yes! Exactly! Without braces I have experienced some issues in some tikzmath operations. Thanks for noting this.

Comment: What's the reason for `\tikzmath`? Isn't `\def\test{\text{b}_{\text{b}}}` sufficient?

Comment: @egreg I have been using `\tikzmath` for writing some tikz parametric packages, which I have to define many `tikzmath` macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `\noexpand` can fix it directly.  But I would think the robustify approach makes more sense if this is an ongoing issue.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

%%%To fix the text subscript
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\makeatletter
%\robustify{\text}
%\makeatother 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node at (0,0) {$\text{b}_\text{b}$: Correct};

    \tikzmath{let \test=\text{b}_{\text{b}};}
    \node at (0,-1cm) {$\test$: Not Correct};

    \tikzmath{let \test=\text{b}_{\noexpand\text{b}};}
    \node at (0,-2cm) {$\test$: Corrected with noexpand};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The screenshot doesn't reflect the real output (in my output, with TeX live 2018, the $b_b$ in the middle is the same as the $b_b$ in the top, and therefor "is correct").

Answer (score 5):

You can see what's going on if you add `\show\text` after the `\tikzmath` declaration:

```
> \test=macro:
->\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \hbox {b}_{\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \hbox {b}}.
```

Indeed, the definition of `\text` is found in `amstext.sty`:

```
% amstext.sty, line 28:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\text}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text@\else\expandafter\mbox\fi}
```

You also have to know that `\tikzmath` does full expansion; since `\text` is not found in math mode, it just does `\mbox`. Since at the time of `let` the meaning of `\protect` is `\relax`, it goes on untouched; then the conditional is expanded and since TeX is not in math mode, you get `\mbox{b}`, which becomes

```
\leavemode\hbox{b}
```

and finally `\unhbox\voidb@x\hbox{b}`. This should explain the output of `\show` above.

Possibly you want to evaluate something instead of having `b` in the argument to `\text`; in this case you need to be careful about what to fully expand and what not.

```
\tikzmath{let \test=\noexpand\text{b}_{\noexpand\text{b}};}
```

will do, but if instead of `b` you have something like `\textbf{abc}`, this will die horribly anyhow.

You need `\noexpand` in front of *both* occurrences of `\text`, in order to suppress its expansion and get the right version when `\test` is indeed used in math mode.

Comment: I think it is `\show\test` that gives you the `> \test=macro:`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing to do is to use \mathrm{}. So it would look something like this:

```
  \node (nodelabel) [base] {$\mathrm{Text_{subscript}}$};
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Swapping `\text` for `\mathrm` doesn't resolve the OPs issue `\tikzmath{let \test=\mathrm{Text_{subscript}};}  \node at (0,0) {$\test$};`.